Do alpha and beta particles have the same energy regardless of its source?
The dangers of nuclear radiation are often described in terms of its penetration power. For instance, alpha particles can be blocked by a sheet of paper, whereas gamma can be stopped by a thick piece of lead, etc. While this description is a practical one, it seems insufficient. Can the same alpha particle in a cyclotron, for instance, be stopped by a mere sheet of paper? Do all radioisotopes emit beta and alpha with the same energy?

It is less about the energy and more about the interaction of the radiation with the material which is also a function of the energy. Alpha particles (Helium nuclei) have much higher cross sections than electrons/positrons. But yes, higher energy should also mean higher penetration. See, for example, this comprehensive explanation.

@zimmervi Thanks. I ask because a YouTuber claims the radiation found in the Van Allen which consists of alpha and beta particles can be easily shielded with a thin sheet of metal. When I researched this, an article claims the beta particles in the lower belt have around 50Mev of energy, which is equivalent to energies produced in a cyclotron.

Given that alpha particles are at best a very minor component of the Van Allen belts, I doubt the YouTuber knows what they are talking about. Different parts of the belts are either primarily protons or primarily electrons.

I don't know what fraction of 50Mev electrons could pass through "a thin sheet of metal" without interacting, but for the ones that are stopped by the metal, that's just the beginning of the story. When high-energy electrons interact with metal, you get a shower of high-energy photons. When any of those photons interact with the metal, you get a further shower of more high energy electrons. Wash, rinse, repeat until the energy of the particles is too low to worry about...

...sometimes thin "shielding" against radiation can be worse than no shielding at all.

So how do those high orbit satellites survive in space. If I'm correct, they're located in the outer van allen belts.
